# Crawling/Scraping data from mobile

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a Python script(using selenium) to **scrape** data from Google by searching for a particular product in google and get all necessary information.

Now there is a requirement of getting this data from Mobile as the search results from google and Mobile is entirely different.So we would like to **scrape** the data from a mobile.

How can i do that?

In the current setup i have scheduled this Python script in Jenkins to automatically crawl and **scrape** the data from Google.

But for getting data from Mobile , How can i approach this? Your suggestions will be very helpful?

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

for row in serach_url_list:
         sleep(30)
         mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Nexus 5" }
         options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
         options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
         options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
         options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
         options.add_argument('--headless')
         browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/chromedrive/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
         browser.implicitly_wait(30)
         
          passed_url=''
          passed_url=str(row)
          get_products(passed_url)


def get_products(url):
    product=[]
    print('Passed URL : '+url)
    browser.get(url)
    names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pymv4e']")
    product.clear()
    upd_product_name_list=list(filter(None, names))
    product_name = [x.text for x in upd_product_name_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the mobile emulation feature within ChromeDriver for selenium. The following resource have Python code examples:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

Comment: Above is a code sample which i use in the PC to scrap data,So as per your suggestion i have added the mobile emulator parameters in above.But this "driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

                          desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())", What this line of code will do ?

Comment: Also we don't need to simulate any mobile environment using Xcode/Android Studio ? The above will work from a mobile context  if i Just change the parameter "options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)"?

Comment: Also could you please suggest what change i need to do on the above code?